# How to load Parquet driver in GDAL with c# wrappers?

Tags: gdal, c#, geoparquet

I am using .Net nugets for GDAL and GDAL.Plugins. In GDAL documentation, in order for Parquet drivers to work, GDAL needs the Apache Arrow C++ library (https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/parquet.html). How can I include Parquet drivers in GDAL with the .Net wrappers?

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from a post by [Tom Augspurger on GitHub](https://github.com/opengeospatial/geoparquet/discussions/101). I had your exact question and this code worked for me:

```
export URL="path_to_your_file.parquet"

export SAS_TOKEN="your-sas-token"

ogrinfo "/vsicurl/${URL}?${SAS_TOKEN}"
```

This created the equivalent output for me:

```
1: name_of_layer_1 (GeometryType of layer_1)
```